# Does Google Play allow you to upload Android Wear and Phone app with same package

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I am learning Android Wear these days I noticed that you need to upload the Android Wear App with same package name as your android app.

Does Google Play allow you to upload these two App (Android Wear and Phone app) with same package ? If this support in case of Android Wear then What extra things I need to do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I answer this question on your other question here:

[Android Wear + Phone App on Google Play Developer Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200098/android-wear-phone-app-on-google-play-developer-console)