# Android Wear + Phone App on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I am learning Android Wear these days and already worked on Android mobile apps. So I want to know if I publish my android wear and phone app from Google Play Developer Console.

So in that case Do I need to add it as different application for android phone and wear app on Google Play ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

the Wear app is packaged inside the Phone app. Once installed on the phone, the phone wil "sync" with the Wear device and send the wear.apk to the Wear device.

That meaning, it's only 1 app in the Google Play dev console.

If you start a new Wear Project template on AndroidStudio you'll see the base structure to make this work.