# How to make an Android Wear app downloadable from your phone's play store?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I've published an Android Wear app and want to be able to download it to my watch from my phone.

I've tried both packaging it as a single mobile app with a linked watch app (like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201084/5946933), as two separate packages uploaded to the play store.

In both cases, I'm able to get the app on my watch, but only from the Play Store on my watch, not from the Play Store on my phone.

This is what it looks like for my app:
[image]

And this is want I want it to look like:
[image]

I have two modules, `wear` and `mobile`, and the build.gradle of `mobile` contains the dependency `wearApp project(":wear")`. Additionally, both package id's are the same, but the version codes are different.

What am I doing wrong here?